# ng-repeat wont work in directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use ng-repeat in directive template like this:

JS

```
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);

module.directive('direct', function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: "directController",
        // This HTML will replace the direct directive.
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {title: "@"},
        template:
            '<div>'
            // print: this is a title, which is correct
            + '{{title}}'
            + '<br>'

            // print: ["1","2","3"], which is correct
            + '{{list}}'
            + '<br>'

            // doesn't print anything, why ?!                
            + '<div ng-repeat="l in list">{{l}}</div>'
            + '</div>',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller)
        {
             // scope has list in it
             console.log(scope);
        }
    }
});

module.controller('directController', ["$scope", function ($scope)
{
    $scope.list = ["1", "2", "3"];
}]);


angular.bootstrap($('html'),['myModule']);
```

HTML

```
<direct title="this is a title"></direct>
```

result HTML

```
<div>
    this is a title
    <br>
    ["1","2","3"]
    <br>
</div>
```

As shown above, ng-repeat doesn't print **'list'**, 
while printing list or logging it, it works fine, why :( ??

---

## Update:

The problem was using the angular bootstrap function to register the module, since I didn't use the `ng-app="myModule"` directive.

If I use the `ng-app="myModule"` directive or inject to the `var module = angular.module("ng");` module it should do the trick.

Comment: You have an unclosed string after the `<br>` following `{{list}}`

Comment: sorry about that, it was typing error, but this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to wrap the angular bootstrap in the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap($('html'),['myModule']);
});
```

Checkout here: http://jsfiddle.net/CRWAv/

Comment: great thanks, but why when printing the list worked, and when repeating it did not? is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Documention](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) says that you have to do that on manual bootstrap:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']);
});
```